# Is Captain America a virgin (in the MCU)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, sexuality

The romantic aspect of Steve Roger's life has been explored in each of the Captain America films.

After being unfrozen, I recall Natasha asking him if he's ever kissed anyone since the 40's. In addition, he was trying to explore the interest of the young lady who was protecting his apartment (Sharon Carter)

**So is the MCU version of Captain America/Steve Rogers a virgin?**

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you are asking the question, or what relevance to the story it adds? To be honest I think the only character we know for sure from things shown on the screen are not virgins are Tony and Clint...

Comment: @Skooba Sure.  I love the character and it's been pointed out a few times, by Black Widow and his neighbor in Civil War for example, that this is of concern because a person such as Cap has little happiness in his life.

Is there any other MCU character where they point out he's forlorn? 

In my original question I had "And if so does it make you sad?"  YES! It DOES! .. Yet that was eliminated because they think it's what, a joke?

The authors of the MCU to be a romantic tragedy. Did people not care about the arc of Quill and Gamora?  Well obviously so why doesn't the same apply to Cap?

Comment: Just as an observation, typically the site users don't respond well to questions about sex/sexuality unless there is a solid reason and perhaps some research on why you think this might be the case. I believe the last part was removed because it invites opinion into the answers, which isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Skooba Ok. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Well why not. 

If it's that bad of a question why can't I delete it for the sake of the integrity of ths Stack?  
WHY???

Comment: ^ lol! not down-voted myself (was tempted to, it definitely _was_ my first instinct), it may be that at first glance your question feels like mocking, "mock the noble Cap will you?" _**Down-votes ahoy!**_

Comment: @RandyZeitman Well look at this way, with two up-votes now you are "rep positive" even with the down-votes. And there are two good, if not conflicting answers (if I do say so myself). Maybe a turnaround in the voting will come.

Comment: The answers posted so far both redeem the question - whose only fault was to not put enough words around it to keep people from thinking it was flame-bait.

Comment: The reason it's been poorly received is largely because we have a long history of troll questions that suggest a character is gay, asexual, a virgin, or whatever based on broad stereotypes of those groups, as well as similar questions asked about sexual minutiae out of obviously pornographic interest (one particularly bad one about Supergirl, another about Daenerys). One *notorious* question asked whether Steve in particular was gay because he shows emotions and isn't a sexual predator. So people were primed to be suspicious from the outset.

Comment: @Adamant Cap's relationships are the focus of scenes in the movie. There's no inference being attempted.

Comment: @RandyZeitman - Well, that's why I reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 13):

**According the writers (Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely) Steve is not a virgin in the MCU.**

[In this "The B-Movies Podcast"](http://www.craveonline.com/entertainment/985969-captain-america-civil-war-writers-b-movies-podcast#/slide/1) at about 23:40:

> Interviewer [William Bibbiani]: This might seem like a base question, this might seem like something that would get asked in Mallrats, but I actually think it's relevant. After all this time-
>
> **McFeely: Steve's not a virgin.**
>
> **Interviewer: Steve is not a virgin?**
>
> **Markus & McFeely: No.**
>
> Interviewer: Okay.
>
> McFeely: I actually think he was not a virgin in 1943. He went on the USO tour! He looked like Chris Evans!
>
> Interviewer: But he thought it was fondue!
>
> McFeely: That's just lingo from Howard Stark! It's not that he doesn't know where the parts go!
>
> Markus: There was an innocence in the 1940s about what you could talk about-
>
> McFeely: Yes
>
> Markus: But not about what you could do.

Comment: You know, even from one of the writers I don't find that persuasive, before he got the upgrade he was a skinny unattractive socially ostracized outcast it's hard to imagine "getting any" ~ after the upgrade to Cap. (& before, pretty much from the moment he met her really) he definitely had a "thing" for agent Carter & he's depicted as such a goody two shoes I find it hard to believe he'd have gone off the reservation with any groupies on the USO tour while holding a torch for her ~ and we know he never got that first date with her ~ that only leaves after he came out of the ice.

Comment: @Pelinore I think the time period McFeely is talking about (the USO tour) is the time between the experiment and when he ships out for Europe (where he reconnects with Peggy Carter). From the movie, he seems to only kindle something with her beyond a friendship after he arrives in Europe and rescues Bucky. Some months go by between then and when he goes down into the ocean.

Comment: @TylerH - The United Service Organizations (USO) tour is when he's in Europe entertaining the troops ~ it's not a period before he ships out to Europe (which is how I read your comment?) ~ there's not really any time we're shown or I'm otherwise aware of between his conversion with the serum & the start of that tour?

Comment: @Pelinore he's in Europe at the *end* of the tour (or at least, the end for him... since he runs off). He tours around America selling bonds for weeks, if not months, before traveling to Europe.

Comment: @TylerH - Ah! Gotya, doesn't change my thoughts on it though ~ I can't see him "getting any" before the serum ~ & he meets (& falls for) her before the serum & I can't see him stringing anyone else along while he's holding a torch for her (seems out of character for our boy scout in stars & stripes) ~ & we know he didn't get that first date with her ~ so again, that only leaves after he comes out of the ice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90906/discussion-between-tylerh-and-pelinore).

Answer (score 6):

### No.

##### Steve Rogers is not a virgin. He lost his virginity to a girl in 1943 on the USO tour.

Bruce Banner, Steve Rogers' co-Avenger and friend, reveals this to Jennifer Walters (She-Hulk) in the mid-credits scene of *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* S01E01, "A Normal Amount of Rage":

> **Jennifer:** [*Drunk crying*] It's just so sad. Steve Rogers did so much for his country and he never got to experience sex.
> [*Crying*]  Did you see that ass? Like, that ass did not [*Cries*] deserve to die a virgin. It's, like, so sad.
> **Bruce:** Steve Rogers is not a virgin. He lost his virginity to a girl in 1943 on the USO tour.
> **Jennifer:** Yes! I knew it.
> **Bruce:** You're not drunk?
> **Jennifer:** [*Shouts*] CAPTAIN AMERICA FU…!!! [*Scene abruptly cuts off to credits*]

[image: Jennifer explaining to Bruce her theory about Captain America's virginity]

The context to the above scene was that earlier in the episode, Jennifer was relating her theory to Bruce that Captain America was a virgin (probably referencing the real-life fan speculation and in keeping with the self-referential and fourth-wall-breaking nature of the show and She-Hulk).

> **Jennifer:** Okay. So, back to what I was saying before, my theory.
> **Bruce:** Oh, God.
> **Jennifer:** Um, Steve Rogers did not have a girlfriend before he went into the service.
> **Bruce:** Says who?
> **Jennifer:** The History Channel. So, he becomes Captain America. And from that moment on, a symbol of America, he is rushed to the frontlines, he becomes a war hero. Then he is frozen in ice.
> **Bruce:** Right. Right.
> **Jennifer:** So, based on everything you've told me, after he gets unfrozen, he goes from world-threatening disaster to world-threatening disaster. That's when he's not a fugitive from the law, right? So it seems like he was pretty, pretty busy.
> **Bruce:** All you're doing is repeating everything that I've already told you about my friend and colleague.
> **Jennifer:** Obviously, Captain America was a virgin.

Answer (score 4):

Chris Evans himself, at one point in time, assumed that Cap was a virgin but this isn't conclusive proof either way as Chris doesn't appear 100% sure himself.

> **A love interest?**
>
> It’s funny when you think about it — he’s probably a virgin. [Laughs.] He’s probably a virgin! I don’t know when it would’ve happened.
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, 'Avengers: Age of Ultron': Chris Evans wonders … Is Captain America a virgin?](https://ew.com/article/2015/04/28/avengers-age-ultron-chris-evans-wonders-captain-america-virgin/)</sub>